Evaluate Postfix and Logical Operators in C with no short-circuiting approach
I came across this question when studying logical operators and conditionals in C.
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int x = 3;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
    printf("Result #4 = %d\n", x++ <= 3 || y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3);
    printf("x: %d y: %d z: %d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;

}

Output:
Result #4 = 1
x: 4 y: 2 z: 3

I do not understand the last line of output. The values for x, y, z do not match my understanding.
Here is my line of thought.

The expression x++ <= 3 || y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3 will be evaluated like : x++ <= 3 || (y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3).
Then, y++ >= 2 will be true and y value will be incremented to 3.
Then, z++ != 3 will be false and z value will be incremented to 4.
Since the whole condition is false, the RHS of the OR conditional will be evaluated.
So, x++ <= 3 will be evaluated to true and x will be incremented to 4.
The whole condition will be true since x++ <= 3 will be evaluated as true.

I tried to find the reference textbook or worksheet from which this question was taken, but I was not able to. I did some research on StackOverflow and I don't think this is a short-circuited condition. If it were, I don't understand why.
The only explanation I can come up with is that the x value will have the side effect implemented (x incremented) because it is evaluated as true, while the rest of the OR statement will not have its side effects since it is evaluated as false, therefore y and z will not be incremented. Is this the case?

Better not to have side-effects in a conditional expression that might be short-circuited. Even if it works correctly, it's better to be kind (to future code readers) than clever.

Operator || is calculates from left to right. If the first part is true, then the final result of the expression is known (true) and the right part is not executed.

If you replace || by | and && by & it will work like expected. But the bitwise operations works only, because all terms here are evaluates by false or true (== 0 or 1).

"I don't think this is a short-circuited condition" You are wrong. "Short circuit" explains everything, in fact only x++ <= 3 is evaluated and the rest is ignored.


The expression x++ <= 3 || y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3 will be evaluated like : x++ <= 3 || (y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3).

If you think in terms of parentheses then why do you apply them at the right side only and not at the other side? The expression would be rather evaluated like  (x++ <= 3) || (y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3).
Why do you assume that the right side is evaluated first? Equal parts are evaluated through left to right.
int x = 3 and x++ <= 3 is evaluated first: 3 <= 3 is true and x gets 4. The right side is not evaluated, y and z keep their initial values.

To answer your question, I was thinking of it the same way as arithmetic operators. Suppose x = 4 + 3 * 8. So it will be x = 4 + (3 * 8), and the last part will be evaluated first. Resulting in x = 4 + 24 which will then be x = 28.

This is not quite correct. Your case is like 0 * (5 + 6). The right part does not need to be evaluated.

What do you mean it doesn't need to be evaluated?

@Salma Ihab Hamed, Re "So it will be x = 4 + (3 * 8), and the last part will be evaluated first.", Not so. The standard doesn't define the operand evaluation order of +. 4 could be evaluated before or after (3 * 8).   In fact, there are MANY valid orders for 4 + (3 * 8): 1) 4,3,8,*,+, 2) 3,4,8,*,+, 3) 3,8,4,*,+, 4) 3,8,*,4,+, 5) 4,8,3,*,+, 6) 8,4,3,*,+, 7) 8,3,4,*,+, 8) 8,3,*,4,+. As long as it produces the correct result, the language doesn't specify how to get there.

@3CxEZiVlQ Re "The right part [of 0 * (5 + 6)] does not need to be evaluated.", hmmm, I think that's incorrect. I think C requires the evaluation of both of *'s operands. It doesn't make a difference for 0 * (5 + 6), but it does for 0 * function_with_sideeffects()

@ikegami The talk was about the human math.

You correctly wrote that

The expression x++ <= 3 || y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3 will be evaluated like
: x++ <= 3 || (y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3).

Now let's read the C Standard about the logical OR operator (the C23 Standard, 6.5.14 Logical OR operator):

3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.
4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
operand is not evaluated.

So as the first operand that is the expression x++ <= 3 evaluates to logical true (its result is equal to 1) then the second operand (y++ >= 2 && z++ != 3) does not evaluate. It means that the variables y and z stay unchanged.
Pay attention to that (6.5.8 Relational operators):

7 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.119). The result has
type int.

and secondly (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators):

2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
operand. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
it).

That is in the first operand of the logical OR operator there are compared the value of the variable x before its increment that is equal to 3 with the integer constant 3. And in the next printf statement  there will be outputed already incremented variable x.

This expression is evaluated this way:
int result;
if(x++ <= 3)
{ 
    result = true
}
else
{
    result = false;
    if(y++ >= 2)
    {
        if(z++ != 3) 
        {
           result = true;
        }
    }
}   

